# An error occurred while attaching a database(s)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have downloaded a sql server .mdf and .ldf file from web and when I try to attach it with my sql server 2014 (Using Management Studio) I am getting the below error.

Attach database filed for server 'MyServer\SQLEXPRESS'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Additional Information
An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
(Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

Directory lookup for the file "C:\Leave Management\App_Data\Leave.mdf" failed with the operating system error 3 (The system cannot find the path specified.)  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5133)

Any suggestion about what I am doing wrong and how to handle this error?

I kept the database file in
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA

Script I received while attaching the file

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [C:\LEAVE MANAGEMENT\APP_DATA\LEAVE.MDF] ON 
( FILENAME = N'C:\Leave Management\App_Data\Leave.mdf' ),
( FILENAME = N'C:\Leave Management\App_Data\Leave_log.LDF' ),
( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA' )
 FOR ATTACH
GO
```

Comment: I assume "Leave.mdf" is the file you want to attach? Have you tried putting them in the default SQL Data Directory? You can look that up in SSMS by looking at the properties of the SQLEXPRESS instance. If you attach the DB through SSMS you have the option to generate a script before clicking "OK". Please put this script in the question.

Comment: Are you using SQLExpress which has a 10GB database size limit?... and Leave.mdf is larger than that?

Comment: place the database files in default sql server Data folder and then try .. also verify its instance is it express or local

Comment: @TToni, I edited the post and added the script and the actual file location.

Comment: @Paul Andrew, It's just 2 MB file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the files in the SQL DATA directory try executing this script:

```
CREATE DATABASE [LEAVE] ON 
  ( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Leave.mdf' ),
  ( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Leave_log.LDF' )
  FOR ATTACH
```

Comment: When I run the code this error appears.  Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.

Comment: FOR is underlined with red color and when I take the mouse over FOR statement it pops up the below message.  Expecting '(', ID, or PRIMARY.

Comment: I edited the post to remove the last comma (between `)` and `FOR`). It might not be visible yet.